# Getting string value from JComboBox in java

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jcombobox

I'm doing a  testJComboBox program. Once I select the outputs of the jCombobox, I would get the string value that I need. However, it doesn't work.

**Here's my code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestJCB extends JFrame {

    private JLabel genderL;
    private JComboBox genderJCB;
    private String[] test = {"male", "female"};
    private JButton gB;

    public TestJCB() {

        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        JPanel frame = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel genderL = new JLabel("Gender");
        genderL.setBounds(10, 200, 100, 30);
        JComboBox genderJCB = new JComboBox(test);
        genderJCB.setBounds(60, 10, 100, 30);

        JButton gB = new JButton("Gender");
        gB.setBounds(10, 50, 60, 30);
        aaa a = new aaa();
        gB.addActionListener(a);

        frame.add(genderL);
        frame.add(genderJCB);
        frame.add(gB);
        add(frame);
    }

    public class aaa implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent sHandler) {
            if (genderJCB.getSelectedItem().equals("female")) {
                System.out.print("yes");
            } else {
                System.out.print("no");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJCB test = new TestJCB();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I also tried `combo.getEditor().getItem()` but it did not work.

Comment: don't do any manual sizing/locating (aka: null or absoluteLayout) ever! Instead, use a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: @kleopatra, is it inappropriate to use null layout? should i recode my gui and use a suitable LayoutManager for my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i also tried the combo.getEditor().getItem() but it did not work.

your most important issue is, that you declare variable that never used or initalized

```
private JComboBox genderJCB;
```

because inside public `TestJCB(){` overrode and created

```
JComboBox genderJCB = new JComboBox(test);// same issue with JLabel too
```

if you want to listenening in `ActionPerformed`, then to change that to

```
genderJCB = new JComboBox(test);
```

better could be to read [JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 1):

The error is a NullPointerException. It it thrown here `if (genderJCB.getSelectedItem().equals("female")){`. This occurs because genderJCB is null. Why is this? Didn't you set it here `JComboBox genderJCB= new JComboBox(test);`? No. You made a new local variable, rather than a field, so you never declared the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a posible solution

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel genderL;
    private JComboBox genderJCB;
    private String[] test = { "male", "female" };
    private JButton gB;

    public main( )
    {

        setSize( 400, 400 );
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setLayout( null );
        setVisible( true );

        JPanel frame = new JPanel( );
        frame.setSize( 400, 400 );
        frame.setLocation( 0, 0 );
        frame.setLayout( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        JLabel genderL = new JLabel( "Gender" );
        genderL.setBounds( 10, 200, 100, 30 );
        JComboBox genderJCB = new JComboBox( test );
        genderJCB.setBounds( 60, 10, 100, 30 );

        JButton gB = new JButton( "Gender" );
        gB.setBounds( 10, 50, 60, 30 );
        aaa a = new aaa( genderJCB );
        gB.addActionListener( a );

        frame.add( genderL );
        frame.add( genderJCB );
        frame.add( gB );
        add( frame );

    }
    public class aaa implements ActionListener
    {
        private JComboBox genderJCB;
        public aaa( JComboBox genderJCB )
        {
            this.genderJCB = genderJCB;
        }

        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent sHandler )
        {
            if( genderJCB.getSelectedItem( ).equals( "female" ) )
            {
                System.out.print( "yes" );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print( "no" );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        main test = new main( );
        test.setVisible( true );
    }

}
```